# Docker container took too many storage of disk

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vps

I was use **df -hl** for check the status of my vps, but it is seem like,the Storage is took by docker mutil time(i only have 1 wordpress in this vps, there is no have other project)

today i recived a email from linode, they tell me my Storage is finished

Total: 25600 MB
Used: 25600 MB

i have a wordpress in this vps, which is builded by docker and wordpress

here is the code which from my vps

```
root@localhost:~# df -hl
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            463M     0  463M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  5.9M   93M   6% /run
/dev/sda         25G  5.0G   19G  22% /
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
overlay          25G  5.0G   19G  22% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2ebf8af06fccd1e3a455746e257c990e6d85f848832eaadd636f48d56e6fbefb/merged
overlay          25G  5.0G   19G  22% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/28044ad06cc4b50d58a331cd644a254c7c90480ad04c1686f2974503da1c98de/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/932928ba7b7ccbbb4dd9f05263fadda8c6764ec7185deefc37c0fc555a2c32d5/mounts/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/67d10956ef387af8327570b7013cc113114a48ccf3654f9ee01041e88e740192/mounts/shm
overlay          25G  5.0G   19G  22% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b81fd707a47702b060b462fbb1424bf024c4e593071b0782f4c817ca46a188e2/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/ce2422fff8741ede110a730d1283e0f43792de05a14b2ae9bdb59874fefa5fc2/mounts/shm
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/0
```

```
root@localhost:~# docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
932928ba7b7c        wordpress:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          0.0.0.0:1994->80/tcp             jujuzone_site
67d10956ef38        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/run.sh supervisord…"   7 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp   phpmyadmin
ce2422fff874        mysql:5.7               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 weeks ago         Up 4 hours          3306/tcp, 33060/tcp              db_jujuzone
```

```
root@localhost:~# docker system prune
WARNING! This will remove:
        - all stopped containers
        - all networks not used by at least one container
        - all dangling images
        - all dangling build cache
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0B
```

Comment: could you run `docker ps -a -s ` ?

Comment: Hmm, according to the `df` output you are using only 5G

Comment: Look here, too: [how to clean up docker overlay directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712266/how-to-clean-up-docker-overlay-directory).  There are several good tips.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've deleted some files that might still be in use by the system.
Keep in mind that in this case, the `df` command can show a different size from the `du` command.
You can check that with more precision using `du -hc` on the same directories and check if it's total differs from the `df` command.
You can also run `lsof |grep '(deleted)'` to verify which files were left open for the file descriptor.
In this case, you can kill this process and restart the responsible daemon.
After all, you must consider to run `docker system prune` with `-a` flag to also clear unused images and maybe reclaim a little bit more space.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue recently on Ubuntu 20.04 with Docker v19.03.13. I searched through Docker docs and found that this maybe because of a new type of filesystem they introduced. You can read more about it from [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/). The way I fixed it was by editing (creating if not present already) the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file and adding the following lines:

```
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay"
}
```

Then restarting docker using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

I have answered a similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1036377/594297).